# Change language of WSO2 Governance Registry 5.3.0

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I found the issue that this product is only in English. How do I change the language on the interface users (Store/Publishe)?

I translated a lot of the html, hbs and css file, but the big problem for me is the way that the publisher section (for example) I cannot do the translation because the artefact have that name, and i cant change the name of the artefact because it will cause inconsistency...

Example:

[image]

The tag name can be translated using label="", but i cannot do the same with the table name. If i want to change the name "Overview" by "Resumen" in my Publisher section, how I can do that without changing the table name="Overview" in the xml? (I changed the name="Overview" by name="Resumen" and does not show me the content at the publisher)

Thanks!

My RXT File:

```
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-soap-service+xml" shortName="soapservice" singularLabel="Servicio SOAP" pluralLabel="Servicios SOAP" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="27">
    <storagePath>/trunk/soapservices/@{namespace}/@{overview_version}/@{name}</storagePath>
    <nameAttribute>overview_name</nameAttribute>
    <namespaceAttribute>overview_namespace</namespaceAttribute>
    <lifecycle>ServiceLifeCycle</lifecycle>
    <ui>
        <list>
            <column name="Service Name">
                <data type="text" value="overview_name"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Version">
                <data type="path" value="overview_version" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Namespace">
                <data type="text" value="overview_namespace"/>
            </column>
        </list>
    </ui>
    <content>
        <table name="Overview">
            <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
                <name label="Nombre">Name</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
                <name label="Namespace">Namespace</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
                <name label="Versión">Version</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text-area">
                <name label="Descripción">Description</name>
            </field>
        </table>
        <table name="Contacts">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Contact Type</heading>
                <heading>Contact Name/Organization Name</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="option-text" maxoccurs="unbounded">
                <name label="Contactos">Contact</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>Technical Owner</value>
                    <value>Business Owner</value>
                </values>
            </field>
        </table>
        <table name="Interface">
            <field type="text">
                <name label="WSDL">WSDL URL</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="WSDL URL">WSDLHttp</name>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Protocolos de Transporte">Transport Protocols</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>HTTPS</value>
                    <value>HTTP</value>
                    <value>SMTP</value>
                    <value>TCP</value>
                    <value>XMPP</value>
                    <value>JMS</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Formatos del Mensaje">Message Formats</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>SOAP 1.1</value>
                    <value>SOAP 1.2</value>
                    <value>XML</value>
                    <value>JSON</value>
                    <value>HTTP-REST</value>
                    <value>CSV</value>
                    <value>BINARY</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Patrones de Intercambio de Mensajes">Message Exchange Patterns</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>Request Response</value>
                    <value>One Way</value>
                </values>
            </field>
        </table>
        <table name="Security">
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Plataforma de Autenticación">Authentication Platform</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>TAM_WEBSEAL</value>
                    <value>XTS-WS TRUST</value>
                    <value>BuiltIn</value>
                    <value>WSO2 Identity Server</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Mecanismo de Autenticación">Authentication Mechanism</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>OpenID</value>
                    <value>InfoCard</value>
                    <value>Client Certifcates</value>
                    <value>HTTPS Basic Authentication</value>
                    <value>IP Address Filtering</value>
                    <value>WS-Security/WS-Trust Token</value>
                    <value>Others</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Plataforma de Autorización">Authorization Platform</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>TAM_WEBSEAL</value>
                    <value>XTS-WS TRUST</value>
                    <value>BuiltIn</value>
                    <value>WSO2 Identity Server</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Integridad del Mensaje">Message Integrity</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>SSL</value>
                    <value>WS-Security</value>
                    <value>XML Digital Signatures</value>
                    <value>Other</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="options">
                <name label="Encriptación del Mensaje">Message Encryption</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>SSL</value>
                    <value>WS-Security</value>
                    <value>XML Digital Signatures</value>
                    <value>Other</value>
                </values>
            </field>
            <field type="text-area">
                <name label="Comentarios">Comments</name>
            </field>
        </table>

        <table name="Operaciones" columns="3" maxoccurs="unbounded">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Nombre</heading>
                <heading>Descripcion</heading>
                <heading>Prueba</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Nombre">nombre</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Descripcion">descripcion</name>
            </field>
        <field type="text" url="true">
        <name label="url">url</name>
       </field>
         </table>
        <table name="Insumos" columns="4" maxoccurs="unbounded">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Nombre</heading>
                <heading>XML Entrada</heading>
                <heading>XML Salida</heading>
                <heading>XML Ejemplo</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Nombre">nombre</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Entrada">entrada</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Salida">salida</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Salida">url</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Salida2">url</name>
            </field>            
        </table>


        <table name="Endpoints">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Environments</heading>
                <heading>URL</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="option-text" maxoccurs="unbounded" url="true">
                <name label="Endpoint">Endpoint</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>Unknown</value>
                    <value>Dev</value>
                    <value>Test</value>
                    <value>Stag</value>
                    <value>Prod</value>
                </values>
            </field>
        </table>
        <table name="Doc Links" columns="3">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Document Type</heading>
                <heading>URL</heading>
                <heading>Comment</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="text">
                <name label="Document Type">Document Type</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text" url="true">
                <name label="URL">URL</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text-area">
                <name label="Document Comment">Document Comment</name>
            </field>
        </table>
    </content>
</artifactType>
```

Comment: Kindly share the content of your rxt?

Comment: Hi! @thusharaK, I just added the file! Thanks.